# Remove metaboxes from custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I want to remove all the metaboxes added by unrelated plugins to my custom post type, is this possible ?

I know I can use the function remove_meta_box(), but then I'll just remove the ones I currently have, but if any other plugin adds a metabox later on I'll have to manually remove it.

Comment: For that you need to identify meta box position, priority and metabox id.

Comment: @milankyada that if I were to use "remove_meta_box()", right ?

Comment: you can check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code to do that. In my case I have found my metabox id,priority and position.

Plugin have added this metabox `'my-meta-box-id'` to post type `foo`.

Here is the code to remove metabox

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'remove_plugins_meta_boxes');
function remove_plugins_meta_boxes(){
    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['foo']['normal']['high']['my-meta-box-id']);

}
```

By this way you can remove your meta box.

Comment: Thank you very much milan, but this is the approach i wanted to avoid, since i want to prevent any future plugin adding metaboxes to this specific post type.